# Invalid arguments у implode()

Tags: php

Ошибка:

> Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed on line 66.

С чем это может быть связано?

*PHP*:

```
<?
function encode($text, $offset=false) {
    $output = array();
    if ($offset === true) {
        $output['text'] = array();
        $arr = explode(' ', $text);
        foreach ($arr as $val) {
            array_push($output['text'], chr($val));
        }
    }
    else {
        $output['code'] = array();
        $arr = str_split($text);
        foreach ($arr as $val) {
            array_push($output['code'], ord($val));
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

$c = null;
$in = $_POST['text'];
$out = $_POST['output'];
if (isset($in)) {
    if (!empty($in)) {
        if (isset($out)) {
            if ($out == "text") {
                $c = encode($in, true);
            }
            else {
                $c = "Incorrect output mode";
            }
        }
        else {
            $c = encode($in);
        }
    }
    else {
        $c = "All fields is required!";
    }
}
?>
```

*HTML*:

```
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="text">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="output" value="text">Text output
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<div>
```

*PHP*:

```
<?
if (gettype($c) == "string") {
    echo $c;
}
elseif (gettype($c) == "array") {
    $mode = array_keys($c);
    print_r($c);
    if ($mode[0] = "code") {
        print implode(' ', $c['code']);
    }
    else {
        print implode($c['text']);
    }
}
else {
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Конечно же код показывать не надо!

Comment: Ошибка > Invalid arguments passed on line 66 Говорит о то, что неверные аргументы на строке 66. Тут и думать нечего. Если и ошибка не в этом, она исходит от нее.

Comment: О Господи... Пожалуйста, скидывай код, если у тебя ошибка.

Comment: Есть, кстати, большая разница между `Warning` (предупреждение) и `Error` (ошибка).

Answer (score 2):

Изучайте английский, читайте ошибки, смотри логи, читайте документацию!

В строке явного пропущен аргумент

```
print implode($c['text']);
```

Должно быть наверно так

```
print implode('', $c['text']);
```

Comment: ...используйте межушный нервный ганглий...